# Keep "this" in a variable and replace all "this" with this variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style, this, readability

## Context

When I use jQuery, I often need to keep `this` in a variable:

```
var obj = {
    myVar: null,
    myFunction1: function() { ... },
    myFunction2: function() {
        this.myVar = "blabla";
        this.myFunction1();

        var ctx = this;
        $('xxx').click(function () {
            ctx.myFunction1();
        });
    }
}
```

In this case, I replace all `this` with my variable:

```
var obj = {
    myVar: null,
    myFunction1: function() { ... },
    myFunction2: function() {
        var ctx = this;

        ctx.myVar = "blabla";
        ctx.myFunction1();

        $('xxx').click(function () {
            ctx.myFunction1();
        });

        //etc. I do it for all "this" even if I have 15 "this"...
    }
}
```

## Questions

- Is it good practice to keep `this` in a variable? Is there another way?
- Is it good practice to replace all `this` with the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there another way?

You can use [`$.proxy` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
$('xxx').click($.proxy(function () {
    this.myFunction1();
}, this));
```

which obviously overwrites `this` inside the event handler, so you don't have access to the element through `this`.

You can also pass `this` as [event data *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/):

```
$('xxx').click({ctx: this}, function (event) {
    event.data.ctx.myFunction1();
});
```

---

Do whatever you find most readable. I personally just assign `var self = this;` and use `self` inside nested functions and `this` everywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

`this` is different in a different function. Context is different in that situation.

Therefore, it is smart to keep it in a separate variable so you know for sure what context you are talking to.

Within functions where there are sub-functions I recommend this, in a regular function just don't. There is no need there.

*note: You don't replace it, you merely have a pointer to the correct context.*

Answer (score 2):

> Is there another way?

Yes: you could pass the reference to the scope with an anonymous self executed function

```
myFunction2: function() {
    this.myVar = "blabla";
    this.myFunction1();

    (function(outerscope) {
        $('xxx').click(function () {
            outerscope.myFunction1();
        });
    }(this));
 }
```

Anyway, storing a reference as you did is fine (or at least, it is not discouraged as a bad practice from [google javascript style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml)) and it is a widely used common practice.

Answer (score 1):

I use always to create:

```
var _self = this;
```

To be honest I don't know if it is a best practice but since I code in js I saw many people doing that and I feel comfortable in using that.

Comment: ye, you can use everything you want and prefere.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally an accepted pattern, but it can get confusing when you have functions within functions (within func-functions-tions ;-) etc

One way to mitigate this (and an alternative approach in general) is to bind your function to a specific context object. [ECMAScript 5's bind() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) handles this, but probably isn't safe to use in a web environment yet.

For now you can instead use [jQuery's proxy function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
    $('xxx').click(jQuery.proxy(function () {
        this.myFunction1();
    }, this));
```